# Safe operating area for different types of battery chemistry?

Tags: batteries, voltage, battery-charging, safety, undervoltage

I'm trying to find the [safe operating area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_Operating_Area) for various types of batteries; in particular I need minimum and maximum termination voltages, although information on temperature / power / current is also desirable.

For example, I know Li-Ion typically has a safe charge window of about `3.0V` to `4.2V`, and I've heard that NiCd / NiMH should never be discharged lower than `0.8V` / cell.

Are there any authoritative resources that list the safe operating area for a majority of battery chemistry types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a lot to do with a range of battery types in recent years. No one source covers everything or is perfect in it's treatment of a given chemistry, but I have found that **Battery University** usually does a good job of providing accurate, detailed and useful  information.

A look at [Battery university's home page](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/) will immediately show you that this is  a better than usual place to find battery information.

[image]

[Nickel based](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/Nickel_based_batteries)

[Lead based](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lead_based_batteries)

[Lithium based](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lithium_based_batteries)

And much much much more ...

Manufacturer's pages are also an excellent source, although harder to find specific chemistry related material.